# Form in Ajax without using form tag

Tags: php, ajax, forms, email

Currently, I'm working on my form and I've got a problem.

I want to send an email without using a form (just input in a div) like this :

```
  <div class="popup-user modal-chat">
     <div class="arrow-up"></div>
     <div class="test-chat">
        <div class="chat-option" contenteditable="false"><input required type="email"  name="email" class="yourMail" placeholder="Mail"></div>

                <div class="row new-msg">
               <div class="input-field col s9">
                 <input id="sendContent" type="text" class="validate" pattern=".{30,}" required name="message">
                 <label class="active" for="sendContent">Message here</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col s3 button-send">
                 <a class="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light red unvailable send">
                    <i class="material-icons">send</i>
                 </a>
              </div>                   
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

And I want to paste data from : #sendContent and .yourMail to a PHP file using Ajax, but what i tried did not work...

Here is my Ajax, but how to send multiple data to my php ?:

```
        var email      = $(".yourMail").val();
        var message    = $("#sendContent").val();
        console.log(message)
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url: "assets/php/post.php",
                data: {
                 email : $(".yourMail").serialize(),
                 message : $("#sendContent").serialize()
                },
                success : function() {
                    console.log("success");
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("not success");
                }
            });
```

And in PHP I just want to send mail with message content first, so basically it should look like this ?

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $message=$_POST["message"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];`enter code here`
    mail("myemail@mail.com","My subject",$message);  
?>
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: Where is your action attribute ? talking about `url: $(this).attr("action"),` @Lucas

Comment: I don't use `jQuery` but `serialize()`  is used on form elements I believe rather than standard `div` elements...? https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: pass data in Ajax like `data: {
                 email : email,
                 message : message
                },`

Comment: Thank to all of you for fast answer ! Since I posted, I updated things and tried things too and I found a solution

Action was a mistake and i edited this :) (thank you)

For serialize, i use this (and it seams to work):  data: $('.yourMail,#sendContent').serialize(),

But is it the good way ?

Comment: why don't you want to use a form? It doesn't cause a problem really, it can just be invisible markup. And then you can easily serialize() all the inputs within it in a single command.

Comment: Because I made a chat like and I coded it without form (wanted to stay on page after submit), so I wanna try without it :) But thanks for advice, next time i'll use form :)

Comment: "I coded it without form (wanted to stay on page after submit)" ...just because you use a form doesn't mean you have to use a postback. You can stay on the same page - just don't use a "submit" style button (just use a "button" type of button instead), and instead handle the form's "submit" button with JavaScript and then run an ajax request. Seriously you can find loads of tutorials showing you exactly this idea online if you just search a bit,

Comment: I know, but when i'm stuck i wanna find a solution in this way before looking for another way and understand why a way is better than another

But thanks for advice and your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change your data into key/value:

```js
data:{'email': email, 'message':message}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It help me a lot :)